# Nest function in Bigquery SQL standard

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

What is the equal of `nest` function from legacy SQL in standard SQL. I wish to aggregated source and medium as follows:

```
NEST(trafficSource.source + '>' + trafficSource.medium) as source
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `NEST` with `+`, you need to use `ARRAY_AGG` or `STRING_AGG` with `CONCAT`:

```
ARRAY_AGG(CONCAT(trafficSource.source, '>', trafficSource.medium)) as source
```

Or:

```
STRING_AGG(CONCAT(trafficSource.source, '>', trafficSource.medium)) as source
```

The first one returns an array, whereas the second returns a comma-separated string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Array_AGG() function.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg

Comment: Thanks @WOPR. I tried that and it doesn't work. Is it something that I'm missing here?

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Query you tried? Error message you got?