# BigQuery: NEST alternative in Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

What is the alternative of `NEST` function in Standard SQL. I have tried `ARRAY_AGG` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559797/nest-function-in-bigquery-sql-standard) but ARRAY_AGG is returning one row whereas NEST is returning flattened array.

Legacy SQL: NEST 
[image: Legacy SQL NEST]

Standard SQL: ARRAY_AGG
[image: ARRAY_AGG Standard SQL]

Comment: I think `array_agg()` should be doing what you want.  I'm not sure that your use of `nest()` is correct.  It should have a `group by`.

Comment: as fyi: no need in `group by` here - aggregation functions `nest()` and `array_agg()' will behave same from that point (grouping) of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery:

ARRAY_AGG() in Standard SQL **is in fact equivalent** of NEST() in Legacy SQL
They both returns array of elements in one row

The difference is in how UI shows result repeated fields  - for Legacy SQL UI flattens result and that is why you see it as a "flattened array"

You can test it by running below

```
#legacySQL  
SELECT COUNT(1) rows FROM (
  SELECT NEST(x) y
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS x),
    (SELECT 2 AS x),
    (SELECT 3 AS x),
    (SELECT 4 AS x),
    (SELECT 5 AS x)
)
```

with result

```
Row rows     
1   1
```

Have in mind - such flattening in UI happens only for most outer select statement and all inner selects treat NEST as ARRAYS / repeated fields

As of saving result into table - if you want to preserve output of below as repeated field

```
#legacySQL  
SELECT NEST(x) y
FROM (SELECT 1 AS x),
  (SELECT 2 AS x),
  (SELECT 3 AS x),
  (SELECT 4 AS x),
  (SELECT 5 AS x)
```

you need to make sure you have disabled `Flatten Results` for which you also need `Allow Large Results`

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little surprised, but this query:

```
select *
from (select 1 as x),
     (select 2 as x),
     (select 3 as x),
     (select 4 as x),
     (select 5 as x)
```

Returns exactly the same thing as this query:

```
select *
from (select 1 as x),
     (select 2 as x),
     (select 3 as x),
     (select 4 as x),
     (select 5 as x);
```

The issue is, no doubt, the lack of `group by`.  So, I think that a simple `select *` will do what you want:

```
select *
from (select 1 as x union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
     ) n
```

Comment: The difference is due to automatic flattening of repeated fields in the results of legacy SQL queries. You can turn this off under options in the classic UI.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard . . . Thank you for the explanation.  I've never used Legacy SQL extensively, and the behavior of `NEST()` is quite curious given the documentation.